# Fix Resolution in Command Line

Tags: command-line, display, display-resolution, raspberrypi

Just installed Ubuntu Server for RasperryPi 3

`Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1008-raspi aarch64)`

The display resolution is not correct and I can not figure out how to fix it.
The screen text is disappearing off the left side of the TV. I am looking about 2 characters off the left side.

I have tried doing internet search but everything I find either points to a file at `/boot/config.txt` which doesn't exist, or involves a command `xrandr` which I do not have.

This is a command line install without any GUI system at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all about the various options at:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md

In particular, you should be able to resolve your issues using the section on overscan.

HOWEVER, as you have already discovered, in Ubuntu there is no config.txt file /boot.

Instead, you should make the changes to usercfg.txt in /boot/firmware/

Comment: It seems that in Ubuntu 22.04 `config.txt` is back (and `usercfg.txt` is gone)